# Reduce root LVM Parition Centos 6.3

Tags: lvm, partition, centos6

I installed Centos 6.3 as a KVM guest OS, and used the default partition settings.

Now I noticed that my / partition is 50GB and my /home is only 20GB. I want to increase my /home to atleast 50GB and / to 20GB.

How can I do the above without losing any data? If reducing the / partition is risky, can I unmount /home, extend the / partition to 70GB and make /home as a directory on the / partition? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On Linux systems, is easier and safer to extend, but with a good backup (if you have data) shrinking isn't a problem neither.

I belive (correct me if wrong) that you have one disk, one group volum and two logical volums (command `lvs` for show them).

in that scenario, I'll copy /home data to /home_bk folder, then unmount /home, delete the logical volum for /home, extend the remaining volum with `lvextend`, then extend the filesystem and then rename /home_bk to /home.

You dont need to mount it again.

Anyway, LVM is great for shrinking and extending, all the options are good, just remember that **You must shrink the FileSystem BEFORE shrinking the Volum**